# Creating the most efficient custom filter function (for my use case)

Tags: swift, function, generics

So the data I'd like to filter is this: `[Movie]`

and every movie is:

```
struct: Movie {
   let title: String
   let tag: String
   let price: Int
   let genre: String
}
```

There are more properties but to keep it simple I'll stop there.

Now I would like to offer the user some good search options for example:

- *All movies that are below $10 **and** have a genre of 'horror'*
- *All movies that are below $10 **and** have a genre of 'horror' **and** a tag of new*

So a user can enter a search criteria that will give some list that they can then expose to a new criteria.. so just to help explain..

```
below10 {
   genre==horror {
         tag==new   {

                     }
                  }
         }
```

here is what I have so far:

```
func dynamicFilter(title: String = "", genre: String = "", tag: String = "", searchCriterion x: String) -> Bool {
   if title.isEmpty { return false } 
       if title.hasPrefix(x) { return true }
   if genre.isEmpty { return false} .... //And repeat


 }
```

But that function has a flaw in that it will return at undesired spots... Do I need generics here? Maybe multiple functions called by one higher order function?

Comment: Instead of `return true` you should set a flag for each criteria and then check all flags at the end or only work with negative conditions and return false directly and only after the last condition return true

Comment: Ahh gotcha! So something like ["title" : "a", "genre" : "horror", "tag" : ""] and maybe a higher order function iterating over dictionaries and returning some Type

Comment: When I said flag I meant a local variable. `let titleFlag = title.hasPrefix(x)` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the types to check are only `String` or `Int` create a custom protocol to constrain the `value` type to `String` or `Int`

```
protocol StringOrInt {}
extension Int : StringOrInt {}
extension String : StringOrInt {}
```

Then create a `Filter` struct with a `keyPath`, a value of `StringOrInt` and a `ComparisonResult` which is a common type for `<`, `>` and `==`

```
struct Filter {
    let value : StringOrInt
    let keyPath : PartialKeyPath<Movie>
    let ordered : ComparisonResult
}
```

To filter items create an array of `Filter`

```
let filters = [Filter(value: 10, keyPath: \Movie.price, ordered: .orderedAscending),
               Filter(value: "Action", keyPath: \Movie.genre, ordered: .orderedSame)]
```

This will filter all movies with a `price` < 10 **and** `genre` == `"Action"`

---

Finally create a `filterMovies` function which applies the filters to the `Movie` items in the `filter` function of Standard Library. The `Int` values are converted to `NSNumber` to be able to use `compare` and compare against the given `ComparisonResult`

```
func filterMovies(_ movies : [Movie], by criteria : [Filter]) -> [Movie] {
    return movies.filter { movie -> Bool in
        for filter in criteria {
            let value = filter.value
            if let stringValue = value as? String {
                if (movie[keyPath: filter.keyPath] as! String).compare(stringValue) != filter.ordered { return false }
            } else if let intValue = value as? Int {
                let numValue = NSNumber(value: intValue)
                let movieInt = movie[keyPath: filter.keyPath] as! Int
                if (NSNumber(value: movieInt)).compare(numValue) != filter.ordered { return false }
            } else { return false }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure the array of criteria is even needed.  I'm not big into functional programming, but it does have some great ideas in it.  In this case, higher order functions, although that implies functions that return functions. I'm not sure you'd even need to define functions to do that.  Just build closures explicitly.

First define a filter type as a closure that takes a `Movie` and returns a `Bool`:

```swift
typealias MovieFilter = (Movie) -> Bool
```

And define a base "passthrough" filter that always returns `true` as your starting point.

```swift
var filter: MovieFilter = {_ in true }
```

When the user selects "Movies under $10" you'd do something like

```swift
filter = { filter($0) && $0.price < maxUserPrice }
```

Then when they add the restriction on genre to "Horror", you add that in a similar way:

```swift
filter = { filter($0) && $0.genre == userGenre }
```

and so on.

To apply the filter is simple:

```swift
let result = movies.filter(filter)
```

So far that assumes that all the filters are "and" filters.  If they were all "or" filters it would be exactly the same process, but your initial filter would need to return `false` and of course use `||` as the combining operator.

If you let your user build up criteria in a more complex way you can still do this, but you have to save off the different sub-filters and combine them.

For example, the user may kind of like horror films, but loves science fiction so they're willing to pay more for it.  Their search would be something like all horror movies under $10 or all sci-fi movies under $20.

You'd build your the horror critera just as above, and separately build the science fiction critieria, also the same way, and then combine them:

```swift
let filter: MovieFilter = { firstFilter($0) || secondFilter($0) }
let result = movies.filter(filter)
```